# How can I call a Matlab function that takes text input from the command line?

Tags: macos, matlab, shell, command-line

I'm working on a medical robotics project that captures a series of images and then does some processing on them in MATLAB. Since a number of other things have to be done outside MATLAB, I'm using another language for the overall control, and using console commands to trigger other portions.

I have a single .m file with a single function that takes the filepath to the directory the images are in and does all the MATLAB processing. How can I call this from the command line? I've seen `matlab -r "function(input)"` discussed in some other answers here, but it doesn't work for me (I get a syntax error at the open paren). More specifically, I get: `matlab: eval: line 1690: syntax error near unexpected token '('`.

I've seen a few people saying this has to be done by calling a shell script (which I have no idea how to write), but a number of other people saying it's doable without that, can anyone clarify?

Additionally, assuming I've merely botched the `matlab -r` syntax, how does MATLAB know where to find the .m file? Does it need to be in whatever directory I'm running the command from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing you are trying:

```
matlab -r test('hi')
```

and getting...

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

or something similar?

**Answer:** You need to use `" "` around the `function(input)`, ie:

```
matlab -r "test('hi')"
```

This runs `test.m` in my current directory with the input string `'hi'`.

To do this in a shell script named `runmatlabcommand.sh`, in say `bash`, you can just open a file and write:

```
#!/bin/bash
matlab -r "test('hi')"
```

and then execute this script from the command line by typing `./runmatlabcommand.sh`. Make sure the script has execute permissions before you try to run it ;)

Comment: Ah, typo in the question actually. I was doing `matlab -r "function(input)"`, with the quotes as you describe. Do I need the apostrophes around the input?

Comment: @Oblivious Sage Only if `input` is a string.

Comment: @Oblivious Sage Are you sure your script is in your current directory?

Comment: Yes, I'm just testing it using Terminal, and I explicitly moved to the directory the .m script is in before calling the command. I added the apostrophes around the input string but I'm still getting the same error at the open paren. I added the exact error message to the question.

Comment: @Oblivious Sage Ah! That is a syntax error coming from badly formatted code within your MATLAB script. Do you get the same error when you run the script from within the MATLAB terminal.

Comment: Ah, yes! OK, that explains it. Thanks dinkelk!